# I replace java 8 with java 7 android studio error?

Tags: android, android-studio

why I replace JAVA 8 with JAVA 7,Android studio error?

```
> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using  Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:...while parsing android/support/v7/recyclerview/R$attr.class
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:...while parsing android/support/v7/recyclerview/R$dimen.class
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:...while parsing android/support/v7/recyclerview/R$id.class
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.  
 If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:...while parsing android/support/v7/recyclerview/R$styleable.class 
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:...while parsing android/support/v7/recyclerview/R.class
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:...while parsing com/example/administrator/comjarlib/R$anim.class
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
............
```

I think to use retroLambda in Android Studio.

Anyone facing similar issue / resolved can give some pointer to resolve it.

I am using Android Studio 2.1 Preview 3 with grade 2.10

Comment: Did you try adding those two lines to your build.gradle file?

Comment: Did you read the error log?  `If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.`

Answer (score 13):

This one helped me. In your project's main `build.gradle` file add these lines of code into `allprojects` section (or add this section if it isn't there).

```
allprojects {

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.7
        targetCompatibility = 1.7
    }

}
```

Comment: Had this problem upgrading from Studio 2.1 to 2.2 with non-android Jars, this was the answer.

Comment: This is how my build.gradle look like, but it does not work allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.7
        targetCompatibility = 1.7
    }
}

Comment: For me, this ended up working. It seems like the best solution if you have other dependencies that will also throw this error as well.

Answer (score 5):

If I don't get wrong gradle android plugin extends 'java' plugin, so you can just add these two lines in your "android" block in your build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

    ...
}
```

Worked fine for me.