# How to include a java 8 subproject into an Android project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working an android project where the model is written in java alone and a dependency for the rest of the project (view, controller), written in "android-java".
I have recently switched from android studio 1.3 to 2.1 and begun to use java 8 in the model.
It compiles fine insofar as rebuilding the project throws no errors.
(I occasionally get "Lambda expressions are not supported at this language level", but this can be resolved by clicking on the red light bulb which offers to set the language level to 8)
Now, when I run the app, I get ~40 errors that look like this one(with another class file each):

```
...while parsing /foo/ba/xy.class
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192456/i-replace-java-8-with-java-7-android-studio-error) question is very similar, however I can specify that the source of my errors contains no android specific code (and have thus no android-block, in my gradle file).
An obvious choice is now to add

```
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
```

to that submodule's build.gradle file.
This beggs the first question: Why `sourceCompatibility = '1.7'`? I want to use java 8!
But regardless, I don't know how to add these 2 lines the the build.gradle file. The file in question looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.7'
    testCompile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    testCompile 'org.kie.modules:org-apache-commons-lang3:6.3.0.CR1'
}
```

**Attempt 1**: add both lines directly in line 2
get "Lambda expressions are not supported at this language level" again, click red bulb again, `1.7` is changed to `1.8` in both lines.
rebuild succeeds, try running.
get 107 errors as above suggesting I set both to `1.7`.
Set `targetCompatibility` to `1.7` and `sourceCompatibility` to `1.8` because it seems logical:
get

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':xxxxmodel:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Gradle window says

```
javacTask: target release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8
```

I can't find the compiler error output however.

**Attempt 2:** add

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
}
```

Get `Error:Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified.`

Comment: The Android SDK can't compile java 8 code. That simple

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @cricket_007 I know that I can't use java 8 in android itself, but when using a library it shouldn't matter what java version it was written in, right?

Comment: It does matter if that library was compiled in Java 8.

Comment: @cricket_007 that is sad to hear. I had assumed bytecode to be invariant of the version.

Comment: @cricket_007, "The Android SDK can't compile java 8 code. That simple" - that's not true anymore. See https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html But I can't recommend jack for lambdas. Personally still use retrolambda for that

Comment: @Deepscorn - I am aware that the Jack compiler in still in Preview stages

Comment: @cricket_007, I don't use jack. You wount find jackOptions { enabled true } in my configuration, but java version is set to JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 Example: https://github.com/Deepscorn/libgdx-gradle-template/blob/master/android/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue.

In build.gradle file where

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

is written, just replaced the same with

```
allprojects {
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```